# Сбрасывается счетчик в C# SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Добрый день. Или я где-то откровенно туплю или же и правда есть некая загвоздка.

Приложение на ASP.NET MVC, использую SignalR. Имеется тестовый Hub

```
public class HubController : Hub
{

    public int COUNT = 0;

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        COUNT--;
        Tools.log("OnDisconnected: " + COUNT);
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {
        COUNT++;
        Tools.log("OnConnected: " + COUNT);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

}
```

Если открыть несколько вкладок страницы, то в логах будет

> OnConnected: 1
>
> OnConnected: 1
>
> OnConnected: 1
>
> ...

То есть счетчик при каждом подключении обнуляется, а должен расти.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Ну так очевидно проблема не в этом классе. А в том, что ты каждый раз, при открытии новой страницы, создаешь новый экземпляр этого класса.

Comment: Экземпляр этого класса создает автоматически SignalR

Comment: Это не важно, тебе в любом случае надо искать причину почему создаются новые экземпляры. Посмотри стек вызовов. Не исключена ситуация что это его нормальное поведение, а твой счетчик должен быть где-то в другом месте. Это следует из стандартного примера в документации. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr#signalr-hubs

Comment: Знаете, это не совсем такой уж полноценный ответ. На so принято подобные вещи оформлять как комментарии. Давайте придерживаться более высоких стандартов, хорошо?